# Google Cloud SQL date format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I need to create a view with a date column. the innitial format is YYYY-MM-DD, I need DD/MM/YYYY in the view. I tried with DATEFORMAT function but my shell returns that this function does not exist. 
I managed it with the following function but it is quite long, is there another way to reach this?

```
concat(
case when day(O.order_date) < 10 
then concat(0,day(O.order_date)) 
else day(O.order_date) end, "/", 
case when month(O.order_date) < 10 
then concat(0,month(O.order_date)) 
else month(O.order_date) end, "/", year(O.order_date)) as 'Date (Au format JJ/MM/AAAA)'
```

Comment: Is your underlying database MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the function you need is [DATE_FORMAT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) for MySQL, [FORMAT_DATE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) for BigQuery, or [TO_CHAR()](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_char/) for PostgreSQL.

Comment: thanks a lot. indeed date_format  is working perfectly. date_format(O.order_date, '%d/%m/%Y')